# IN MVC 3 how to call a data table value from one method to another method in same controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I created a Data table which is in one method.Data are loaded in to that method.When i click on a button it will call another method which is used to export value of data table in to EXCEl sheet, Value of Data table is becoming NULL here so excel is loaded blank.Below is the code,Help me out

Cshtml Page:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Reports", "GenerateReport", 
          new { area = areaName, controller = "Documents" }, 
                new { @class = "button" })
```

Controller Page:

First Method where Data Table is created

```
public ActionResult Details(int id) {
            Document document = repositories.DocumentRepository.Get(id);
            DocumentModel model = MakeDocumentModel(document);
            //Lincy
            // Here we create a DataTable with four columns.

            dt.Columns.Add("DigitalDocs Profile For:" + model.Document.Attraction, typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("", typeof(string));

            // Here we add five DataRows.
            dt.Rows.Add("Report Run Date: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd,MMMM dd,yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"));
            dt.Rows.Add("");
            dt.Rows.Add("LOOK IN:", "" + model.Document.Attraction.Land.Parkgate.Location, "" + model.Document.Attraction.Land.Parkgate, "" + model.Document.Attraction);
            dt.Rows.Add("TYPE:", "Attraction");
            dt.Rows.Add("PROJECT N0", "" + ProjectNo);


            //Lincy
            return View(model);


        }
```

Second Method to Generate Excel and calling Data table

```
 public ActionResult GenerateReport(DataTable dt)
        {
            try
            {

                    //Common code to export for any formats
                    Response.ClearContent();
                    Response.Buffer = true;
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "DigitalDocs.xls"));
                    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
                    string str = string.Empty;

                    foreach (DataColumn dtcol in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        Response.Write(str + dtcol.ColumnName);
                        str = "\t";
                    }
                    Response.Write("\n");
                    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        str = "";
                        for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
                        {
                            Response.Write(str + Convert.ToString(dr[j]));
                            str = "\t";
                        }
                        Response.Write("\n");
                    }
                    Response.End();
                    // HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
                }

            catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException lException)
            {

                // do nothing

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

            return null;
        }
```

How to get the data table value to this method and display in Excel.

Comment: Can you please elaborate, which method will be called on which action?
and why don't you create a private common method to generate that datatable, and use it rest 2 methods?

Comment: by clicking Button Generate Report method will be called.In the method Details only i can fetch data's for the data table.

Comment: Still I didn't understand what you're trying to achieve, and if `GenerateReport` method will be called on `click of button` then how will you get `DataTable as a parameter`?

Comment: You cannot pass a `DataTable` to a controller method from a view. You need to pass the `id` (as you did in the `Details()` method) and generate the `DataTable` again